# Текстовой редактор Atom Фризит

Tags: css, atom

Пишу совершенно не сложный, не объемный CSS HTML JS код, учусь. Atom в свою очередь почему-то иногда фризиться, просто на несколько секунд, потом продолжает дальше спокойно работать. Пакетов стоит не так уж и много, вряд ли в них причина, не знаю что делать, это раздражает, а редактор сам по себе дико нравиться.

Comment: Установи `sublime text-3` и не парься    http://www.sublimetext.com/3  ...  Я кроме `sublim`, ни один редактор не признаю... Но уважаю еще  `code.visualstudio` https://code.visualstudio.com/

Comment: Я просто изначально начал на Атоме писать, привычка, плюс всё настроил под себя. Sublime ставил, не вкатил, слышал про визуал, думаю попробовать и его.

Comment: Потому-что Atom работает с помощью `chromium`.